# Spiral Abyss Floor 8-2 having trouble getting a single star

Tags: genshin-impact

This floor is mad tough -- I need advice on what teams I should be setting up and how to combat the ruin guards.  The problem isn't the cryo/pyro hilichurls, it's the beefy ruin guards. They seem to have astronomical health values, far too disproportionate compared to their overworld counterparts. I can clear 8-1 and 8-3 with 3* each with no problem, but 8-2 is really starting to wear me out mentally.

I've tried using bow users to hit the weak spot, but even when they are stunned they take virtually no damage. Both of my abyss teams are setup so that they can apply Superconduct when necessary. My carries on both teams are both level 70 with high talent levels and level 70 weapons, with a full set of +16 artifact gear. I must be missing some secret trigger that should work.

Comment: Aren't there videos/streams around already with tutorials/full walktrough? Unless you are hardcore player you should start with those even before attempting the challenge yourself, this saves a lot of trial/error wasted time. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvzloGm5IBQ) is first video I've found

Comment: It would be hard to talk about this without knowing what characters you have available.

Comment: @Sinatr That first video you found doesn't even have a guide to specficially Floor 8-2 and getting 3* there.  My question specifically states I have no issues with the other floors, just this one level in particular.

Comment: @Seiyria It shouldn't really matter -- Floors 6-8 should be about a matter of building the right team comp to put in the right status or right combination.   In Floor 7 I could have cleared the Hydrogunners with Chongyun but Kaeya worked fine for my needs.

Comment: @sayu it absolutely matters. If you have Jean and Diluc, the answer changes compared to if you do not. Same if you have Qiqi and other healers.

Comment: @Seiyria It does not matter.  Answers should be tailored towards specific team setups that can allow for a better time against Ruin Guards.  For example, you can have either Fischl/Venti/Amber, just to temporarily disable them -- meaning that instead of needing to describe those ones specifically, you can mention having an archer.   You can mention specific elemental combos that work best against them, such that very diverse team comps can still do it. This question would not benefit anyone if it only pertained to people with an extremely specific lineup of certain characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ruin Guards have [70% base physical resistance](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/jc7swk/damage_after_defense_calculation_formula_with/), Superconduct only reduces that to 30%, which is still a pretty high value given that most other mobs only have 30% or 10% physical resistance.

In addition, Ruin Guards' elemental resistances are only 10%, so you want to focus on that.

Thus, **you still do not want to be hitting them with physical attacks.** Focus on elemental ones, with characters that hit with elemental attacks as a default. Most of the non-Anemo 5 stars are able to do this, eg. Diluc, Klee, Keqing, Mona. Also you can use Xiangling's or Fischl's E to help with additional damage.

Just put one DPS and one Support DPS on each team, along with a Support/Healer with Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayer (+48% damage for 10s every 20s on character switch) and you should get 3 stars easily - I did this with half of my characters having unlevelled artifacts.

Also it should be said that you should group the Hilichurls together with the Ruin Guard as much as possible, so you don't have to run around trying to defeat them after bringing down the Ruin Guard.

---

Answer (score 1):

Its worth noting that theres an orb in the hall that keeps adding a shield on the ruin guardian.

Removing it with the hardest counter element helps (Ice -> fire) (Fire -> water) before burning any higher damage abilities (Barbara for fireshield, easy)

Answer (score 1):

The ley line disorder of floor 8 increases damage, attack speed and crit rate/dmg the lower health you have, so you should use chamber 1 to get your main dps low health such that you deal way more dmg in chamber 2